# Google Earth stopped working on Debian testing

Tags: google-earth, linux, debian, gpu

Suddenly GE Pro desktop stopped working on Debian testing laptop. I can launch GE, menus work. I can even search for a place and pop up appears but where a map shall be only black screen is. Also there are no items in Places and Layers.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my GPU info:

```
inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Mobile 4 Series Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.7 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
  resolution: 1440x900~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel GM45 Express v: 2.1 Mesa 19.3.3
```

I figured out I'm probably using inappropriate GPU driver but I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

So far I tried to reinstall and downgrade GE, but previous versions depend on lsb-core which is not in use in Debian buster. I also used all option in Launch repair tool. No advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today's Debian update solved everything. Many qt5 libraries were updated. I must keep on my mind what testing version means.